# order of task execution in spark streaming for rdd partition which belongs to two different DStream

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am running a spark streaming application.

consider at time t1 Dstream D1 got created and internally dstream hold 5 RDD(D1R1,D1R2,D1R3,D1R4,D1R5) and evry RDD 
holds 5 partition (for ex partition for D1R1 are named D1R1P1,D1R1P2,D1R1P3,D1R1P4,D1R1P5).

as per my understanding RDD partition and computation constitutes a spark Task.

lets name task corresponding to D1R1P1 is D1R1P1T1.

similarly at time t2 Dstream D2 got created and internally dstream hold 5 RDD(D2R1,D2R2,D2R3,D2R4,D2R5) and evry RDD 
holds 5 partition (for ex partition for D2R1 are named D2R1P1,D2R1P2,D2R1P3,D2R1P4,D2R1P5).

lets name task corresponding to D2R1P1 for same computation is D2R1P1T1.

will spark make sure that task 'D1R1P1T1' completes before execution of task 'D2R1P1T1' in all the scenario(normal run 
without any failure,task failures or node failure).

cosider spark streamig is using receiver less approach (Kafka direct approach).